# исполльзуя reduce преобразовать список в словарь

Tags: javascript

Есть обычный список с цифрами.

```js
[1,2]
```

Я хочу, используя reduce вернуть словарь, вида

```js
{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

то есть

```
[1,2].reduce(myFunc) ====> {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

Для этого нужно написать функцию `myFunc`
Проблема в том, что я не могу осознать, как использовать значение в редюс, куда все будет прибавляться.
Мои не удачные попытки:

```
function myFunc(total, num, index) {
  return `{key${num}: ${num}}`;
}
```

ну это вернет самый последний результат, ну это и логично, так как `total` не используется. Убираем индекс - он не нужен нам и добавляем тотал.

```
function myFunc(total, num) {
  return total[`{key${num}`] = `${num}}`
}
```

Это не рабочий вариант.

```
function myFunc(total, num) {
  return {}, `{key${num}: ${num}}`;
}
```

Как и этот.

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunc(total, num) {
  return total[`{key${num}`] = `${num}}`
}
```

Вы были так близки. Функция, которая передает в `reduce` должно возвращать общий результат, а не конкретный для какой-то итерации.

```
// Это не вернет весь объект total, в этом и проблема.
total[`{key${num}`] = `${num}}`
```

```js
const data = [1, 2];
const result = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[`key${el}`] = el;

  return acc; // Возвращаем именно acc.
}, {}); // Последний аргумент - начальное значение acc.

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `[1,2].reduce(myFunc)` - т.е. нельзя написать просто функцию, которая вернет нужный результат?

Comment: @Serhii да можете в переменную ее вынести. Никто не мешает

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.